# Nested Min Selection | Excel-VBA UDF Parameters

Tags: vba, user-defined-functions

Excel 2015/Access 2015

Primary Function: LavenshteinDistance returns an integer

```
Function LDCellsTwo(sR As Range, tR As Range, IDRange As Range) As Integer
Dim tRNum As Integer: Dim CLVD As Integer: Dim MinLVD As Integer: Dim MinID As Integer
For tRNum = 0 To tR.Count
    CLDV = LevenshteinDistance(sR.Text, tR(tRNum))
    if IsEmpty(MinLDV) then MinLDV = CLDV + 1
    If CLDV < MinLDV Then
        MinLDV = CLDV
        MinID = IDRange(tRNum)
    End If
Next tRNum

LDCellsTwo = MinID
End Function
```

**Edited: Thanks Scott good catches - Still  Resulting In #NAME? error**

Goal: Have the LDCellsTwo Function return the ID value associated with the first lowest LevenshteinDistance value returned by iterating various items in the `t` Range against the single value in the `sR` Range where the `ID` Range and the `t` Range are implicitly the same length

Error: `#NAME?` returned in cell

Comment: Is your function defined in a regular module, or a worksheet module?  Should be in a regular module.

Comment: @TimWilliams, Yes, it's defined in a regular module. I really only use sheet modules for change events. Thank you.

Comment: Since `t` and `ID` are already ranges you do not call them with the `Range()` function, just use the `t` and `ID`. Like: `tr = t`.   Also remove the `()` after each reference to the arrays; note: you should declare these before assigning values.  Also you are not returning anything `LDCellsTwo = Something` at the end.

Comment: @ScottCraner, Yikes yeah good catches there -- can I say it's been a long day? I'm still getting the same errors, but I've implemented your suggestions in the edited question

Comment: have you set a break point @ your for trNum line and stepped through the code?

Comment: now that you are iterating through a range and not an array, `tR(tRNum)` should be `tR.item(tRNum)`

Comment: @Scott yes I had, but it wasn't breaking at all. I ultimately broke it down into several small parts and tested each to find the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Sure why this made such a big deal, but

```
Function LDCellsTwo(sR As Range, tR As Range, IDRange As Range) As Integer
Dim tRNum As Integer: Dim CLVD As Integer: Dim MinLVD As Integer: Dim MinID As Integer
For tRNum = 1 To tR.Count
    CLDV = LevenshteinDistance(sR.Text, tR(tRNum))
    if IsEmpty(MinLDV) then MinLDV = CLDV + 1
    If CLDV < MinLDV Then
        MinLDV = CLDV
        MinID = IDRange(tRNum)
    End If
Next tRNum

LDCellsTwo = MinID
End Function
```

The change was:

from `For tRNum =`**0**`To tR.Count`

to `For tRNum =`**1**`To tR.Count`

Comment: Sorry I missed that, it is because there you changed to iterating through a range and there is no value at tR(0) it starts at 1.